# Scale type for the ImageView

Tags: android

I have image which have size more than imageView. What scale type should i set such that i set completely inside the imageview.

If image have small in size then it should also completely inside the imageview without change in the size and quality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depends on your requirements.

you should use the default one (FIT_CENTER) if:

1. the aspect ratio of the imageview is the same as the image. this will fill the imageview space entirely and perfectly . for example, if both the content and the imageView are squares (width==height), this is just fine.
2. you care about the aspect ratio of the image and also care about showing the entire image. this will cause margins in order to make the content stay with the correct aspect ratio.

if you don't wish to have margins, ever, you use :

1. fit_xy  if you don't care about the image being stretched
2. center_crop in case you don't want it to stretch, yet it's ok with you that parts of the image would be cut out to fill the imageView space.